# An equivalent definition of a group

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, binary-operations

Exercise 15 from Hungerford: Algebra.

Let $G$ be a nonempty finite set with an associative binary operation such that for all $a,b,c\in G\,\,ab=ac \Rightarrow b=c$ and $ba=ca \Rightarrow b=c$. Then $G$ is a group. Show that this conclusion may be false if $G$ is infinite.

I've solved the first part, but I wasn't able to find a counter-example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After you are done solving the problem, the following reference has more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellative_semigroup

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**HINT:** Is there a familiar (infinite) set and commutative operation in which you know that $ab=ac$ implies $b=c$? It's an example you can really count on.

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot!

Comment: So that's what counter-example means!

Comment: It means that the cancellation law in a finite set with an associative binary operation cannot have a goup structure. Am I right? Sorry for the bad English!

Comment: @spohreis: Huh? No. If you have a binary associative operation on a finite set and the operation satisfies both cancellation laws, then the operation makes the set into a group; that's the point of the exercise. If you have a binary associative operation on *any* set (finite or infinite) that does *not* satisfy the cancellation laws, then the operation does not make the set into a group. In an **infinite** set, a binary associative operation that satisfies cancellation may or may not give you a group.

Comment: Sorry, I mean "infinite set".

Comment: @sopohreis: Still wrong: the integers under addition are an infinite set in which you have an associative binary operation which **does** give a group. The point is that for a binary associative operation, cancellation is *enough* in a finite set, but is *not enough* (though it is *necessary*) in an infinite set.

Comment: Ok! How about that? It is because the right (or the left) translation isn't bijective.

Comment: @spohreis: I don't understand what it is you are trying to do/say. What "is because" what? If you are trying to characterize what properties a binary associative operation on an infinite set must satisfy in order for it to give you a group, there are plenty of characterizations. E.g., that all equations $ax=b$ and $xa=b$ have solutions.

Comment: I am happy to be the vote which puts your rep in the 6 figures!! :) Congrats.

Comment: @SteveD: Thanks! But according to the audit I just ran, it's a bit premature. (-: